# Qt: Remove the icon on the top left

Tags: qt

i want to remove the icon on the top left of a qt application. here is my main.cpp code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    Receive receive;
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

//    setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);

    QObject::connect(window,SIGNAL(sendUrltoC(QUrl)),&receive,SLOT(getText(QUrl)));

    return app.exec();
}
```

if i uncomment the commented part it gives me an error. what should i do?

Comment: a) You are not calling setWindowFlags() on any instance of a window. b) The QQuickWindow class has no setWindowFlags() function. You are probably looking for the setFlags() function instead. Try the following replacement for your commented out line: `window->setFlags( Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint );`

Comment: thanks a lot - it's working